# How to find out if an email already exist with jpa spring and sending some error messag to the front end

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

So i have a simple UsersDao

```
public interface UserDao extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

}
```

And inside my user controller i want to do something like this :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void addUser(@RequestBody User user) {

    //How do i check if user already exist with email instead of id
    // i managed to do this but can i search on something else than the id
    User user1 = userDao.findOne(1);

    if (user.getEmail().equals(user1.getEmail()))
    {

        // And how should i give one error to the front end if the email 
       //already exist I'm using angular js

    }
    else {

        userDao.save(user);

    }

}
```

I also have some extra questions on this topic:

Somethings that are not clear are following. I have done a small tutorial on jpa but there they use:

EntityManager,
EntityTransaction

Note : when using EntityManagerFactory  it goes as follow :

```
    EntityManagerFactory emf = null,

    //Then they use EntityManagerFactory

        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("SomeValue")
    //where can i get "someValue" When using application .properties 

//because in the example they use xml but can't find the right properties in application.properties
```

Or do i not need to use these in springboot

Sorry for all these question. I really want to get into spring but somethings are still a bit unclear at this point ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do the following:

Assuming `User` has an attribute `email`, define a method in the interface like this to generate a dynamic query:

```
public interface UserDao extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    public User findByEmail(String email);
}
```

Then you can find a user by email. If `null` is returned, no user with the given email exists. Also, within the `User` entity class, you can define an annotation to ensure that `email` is unique like this:

```
public class User {

    ....

    @Column(unique=true)
    String email;

}
```

Comment: Hi i tried what you said but @column unique true is not working, I can still add multiple users with email. And for some reason if i do something like         User user1 = userDao.findByEmail(user.getEmail());  if(user1.getEmail().equals(user.getEmail())) i get NullPointerException any ideas how to approach this

Comment: Ok i got it working But for some reason unique=true does not work and i have to catch this in the database

Comment: For the NullPointerException, check if user1 is null before checking the email equality. The @Column annotation is a directive for generating the ddl. If you are not automatically generating the ddl then it would not work.

Answer (score 6):

You have 2 options:

1. Use method `User findByEmail(String email);` in repository interface.
2. Use method like
   `@Query("SELECT COUNT(u.id) FROM User u WHERE u.email=:email) Long
   countUsersWithEmail(String email);`
   Than it's obvious how to use rusults of these queries. I would use 2nd choice because of smaller overhead.

Comment: there's technically a race condition there. It's better to try to save the user by email and catch a unique key violation

Comment: `findUserByEmail` will throw a `NonUniqueResultException` exception if that email already exist

Answer (score 2):

this can actually be done in two different ways. although @ufuoma's solution is valid, spring has the exists and Optional which are more flexible. i will give code examples of each.
in the repository interface, we will have these methods

```
boolean existsByEmail(String email);
Optional<User> findByEmail(String email);
```

then in your Service class we will have

```
    public Optional<User> findByEmail(String email){
       return baseUserRepository.findByEmail(email);
    }

    public boolean exist(String email){
       return baseUserRepository.existsByEmail(email);
    }
```

then in the controller class, we will have

```
if(baseUserSevice.exists==true){
    return "User already  exist";
}
```

or

```
Optional<baseUserEntity> user=baseUserService.findByEmail(user.getEmail);
if(user.isPresent()){
   return "user already exists";
}
```

the exist method is most preferred since it's faster

Answer (score 1):

you can use any combination with **exists** keyword

```
public interface UserDao extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    public boolean existsByEmail(String email);
}
```